# Scheme Error: Cannot read property 'car' of undefined []

Tags: recursion, scheme

I want to write a recursive function that takes a list, and returns the sum of factorials of the
elements of the list. Calling the factorial function defined above.

For example (sum-of-factorials-of-elements ‘(1 3)) should return
(+ (factorial 1) (factorial 3)) => 7

But I got error `Cannot read property 'car' of undefined []` I also used the `cond` structure, but this time it gave an error that `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined []`.    I'm quite new to this language, I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: You have another typo: `(if (null? lst)) 0 ...)` needs to be `(if (null? lst) 0 ...)`, that is, you have a misplaced parenth in the `if` expression. After fixing that, the code seems to work for me. Did you reload the file after you fixed the first typo (fixing `remaining` --> `list`)?

Comment: Those errors you are seeing look like JavaScript errors. Where are you running this scheme program?

Comment: [Classmate of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498389/scheme-car-of-undefined)? Earlier question with very similar code and the exact same mistake about misplaced parenthesis.

Comment: @Thankyou I'm running in Repl.it .

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that the variable remaining appears to never have been assigned to store any value. So it is a malformed list, Scheme interpreter doesn't like it. Did you mean (car lst)?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it incorrectly, but it gives the same error with car lst.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched brackets, specifically in `(if (null? lst))` -

```scm
(define (factorial n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

(define sum_of_factorials_of_elements 
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)                  ; <-
        0
        (+ (factorial (car lst))
           (sum_of_factorials_of_elements (cdr lst))))))


(sum_of_factorials_of_elements '(1 3))
```

```scm
7
```

For Scheme beginners, I would highly recommend a development environment suited for the language. [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org) gives you a bracket pair highlighter and automatic indentation (and much more).

Comment: PLT Scheme (now known as "Racket") is quite possibly my favourite language of all time. If you run into other trouble with this beautiful language, be sure to ask for help. Me or many others that come to mind will be happy to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This is either a non comformant Scheme implementation or a R5RS comformant Scheme. The R5RS report has an easy ring to it and states that in the event you feed it code that is not valid Scheme any response would be considered acceptable. Your code is not valid Scheme since you have misplaced parentheses:

```
(define sum_of_factorials_of_elements 
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst))
    0
    (+ (factorial (car lst)) 
       (sum_of_factorials_of_elements (cdr lst)))))
```

The `if` has only one part while the bare minimum since R4RS is 2. It seems to me that the rest of the code, now interpreted as continuation expressions in the procedures body, was supposed to be parts of the `if`. Eg.

```
(define sum_of_factorials_of_elements 
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        0
        (+ (factorial (car lst)) 
           (sum_of_factorials_of_elements (cdr lst))))))
```

Having an editor that balances and indents your code so that you can see the error is a very good tool that ensures you won't waste time on silly mistakes like this.